# Как посчитать количество элементов на странице после удаления?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице 10 элементов `div` с классом `item`.
При нажатии на данный див происходит `.remove()` jquery и через AJAX удаляется элемент.
Теперь после применения `remove` мне нужно посчитать сколько данных `div.item` есть на странице, через инспектор кода посчитал 9, а вот скрипт считает на 1 больше, сначала 10(но их 9), потом 9( но их 8).

```
$('.item').click(function () {

    var divNumberOnPage = $('.item').length;

    console.log(divNumberOnPage);

    var setCurrentPagination = $('.number').html(divNumberOnPage);

    return setCurrentPagination;
});
```

Comment: предосталенный код считает верно. либо мало кода, либо на результат влияет что-то другое

Comment: а где в коде _При нажатии на данный див происходит .remove() jquery и через AJAX удаляется элемент._? Могу предположить, что выводится число _до_ удаления, поэтому кажется, что была ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> и через AJAX удаляется элемент

Это как?

Через AJAX  элементы не удаляются - через ajax происходят запросы. Возможно ошибка в том, что вы удаляете элемент в callback-е аякса (`complete: function(r){..}` или `success: function(r){..}` или `.done(function(r){..})`): после совершения запроса. А считаете количество вне коллбека, например после вызова `jQuery.ajax`.

В таком случае ошибка в понимании,  поскольку ajax-ответ придёт позже (и выполнится callback), чем выполнится следующая строчка после  `jQuery.ajax` .

А алгоритм подсчёта - верный.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что считать надо в том же обработчике, что и удалять. А то ты посылаешь запрос, пересчитываешь элементы - их всё ещё 10, потом обрабатываешь ответ и один удаляешь.